# How to sort the product collection by a custom parameter?

Tags: product, collection, magento-1, sorting

In my file, the **$ranking** of each product is an integer numeric value derived from a particular formula.

```
$productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
     ->getCollection();

foreach($productCollection as $product){
     $ranking = formula; //integer numeric value
}
```

I want to sort the products according to the **$ranking**.
What should I do?

Comment: use `$productCollection->addAttributeToSort('ranking', 'desc');`

Comment: @Anil Suthar I tried, but can't do it.  $ranking is not an attribute, just a temporary parameter.

Comment: What is the formula??? Where you are saving the ranking for products. if you are saving product ranking in DB then you may use joins in collection.

Answer (score 1):

I reckon you should use `setOrder`:

```
$productCollection->setOrder($ranking);
```

Where `$ranking` should be a valid SQL order statement.